Why does this two-line Python program give variable output under PyCharm?
Using Windows 7, python.exe 3.8.0 and PyCharm 2019.4.5 with:

this (faulty) program
print("hello", flush=True)
garbage;

seemingly at random gives either:

or

Likewise with "-u":

Why am I not getting the same each time?
Note: I am not asking for a remedy. Just asking for the cause.

You're asking why stdout/stderr are not consistent in the terminal?

I'll stick with the question as asked.

This is not specific to PyCharm, or even to Python. There is no order defined when writes are performed to different files. The print writes to stdout and the traceback writes to stderr. Buffering is unrelated.
The order will be correct if the writes to stdout and stderr go to the same place:
import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
print("hello out", flush=True)
garbage;


Thanks, I don't see how buffering can be unrelated when the output resulting from program line 1 appears after the output resulting from line 2. Surely the former must be being buffered.

@ChrisJJ Running with -u, setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1, and using flush=True are not needed to reproduce this behavior. Buffering is unrelated. Note that stderr is unbuffered by default, stdout is line buffered - and you're printing a full line to stdout already. So using an unbuffered mode is not really doing anything relevant to the question here.

I agree tests show -u or PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 do not affect the result. But I don't agree this shows the issue is unrelated to buffering. Whilst there's no candidate explanation for the reversal other than buffering, then logically the cause must be buffering.

I reiterate, the cause is not buffering, at least not any kind of buffering which you can control from Python itself. The fact that it still happens without running Python unbuffered should be proof enough of that. You need to understand that the subprocess has a file for stdout and a file for stderr, and it's up to the OS when to select those handles for reading and writing. They may both have data available at the same time, and it's the OS which decides who to read/write, not Python.

"They may both have data available at the same time" can happen in this case only if line 1's output is buffered. Because only after line 1 finishes generating output does program execution continue to line 2.

"the cause is not buffering, at least not any kind of buffering which you can control from Python itself. " So, a kind of buffering which we cannot control from Python itself? We're agreed, then.

Yes. The point is that the modes of buffering you're trying to control with -u, PYTHONBUFFERED=1, and flush=True are irrelevant. You may as well remove them from the question, they're red herrings.

They are in because they are an essential part of my question. I wouldn't bother asking the version of the question that doesn't have them, since the answer would be obviously "buffering".

Do you understand that if you're writing to a pipe, the pipe also has a buffer? Python does not know whether the content it has written is buffered in a pipe or written to a file or sent across a network device... that context lies "outside" the Python process itself, and becomes the responsibility of the operating system I/O. The print you have ends in a newline, which means the output isn't going to be buffered regardless - text to stdout is line buffered, it has no chance of buffering here unless you had used end="" in the print call. So, no, they aren't relevant to the question.

The relevance to the question arises from the effect on the reader, not on the computer.

Because PyCharm.
python.exe executed direct does not show this issue. I.e. every time, the output is in the expected order:

PyCharm is evidently buffering stdout.

This is because stdout and stderr are connected to the same TTY device. It does not follow that PyCharm buffering is the cause. The cause is there are two distinct file descriptors for the subprocess output and you have nothing synchronizing the streams.

Try this: I combine streams with subprocess APIs, and stderr gets printed first, even though the script itself prints to stdout first.  No PyCharm involved. "Because PyCharm" is not an answer.

@win "The cause is there are two distinct file descriptors for the subprocess output and you have nothing synchronizing the streams." does not accord with the fact that that factor remains when PyCharm is removed, yet the issue remains.

Try adding print(sys.stdout.isatty()), I expect you'll find it is False when running in PyCharm and True when running directly in the console. But I feel like I'm talking to a wall here, you seem unwilling or unable to verify the evidence I'm presenting.

import sys;print(sys.stdout.isatty()) does do as you predicted.

"you seem unwilling or unable to verify the evidence I'm presenting" I haven't disputed any evidence you've presented.
